# What happens if I exceed the limit of a variable in Java?

Tags: java, numbers, byte

Pretty small question, but I'm intrigued. Say I have the following code:

```
byte b = 123134235;
```

A byte can only store a number of -128 to 127. With this in mind, what happens if I give it the value `123134235` on an 'internal' scale. When I try compiling the code, I get the following error:

```
test.java:10: error: possible loss of precision
```

But what is the Java compiler actually doing? Is it just storing the value as 123... or?

Apologies for my incoherent English, I'm really tired (5am here!)

Comment: It's not going to store anything if it failed to compile.

Comment: Ohhh! I just noticed, I suppose I thought it was a warning from how it was worded, then I noticed the big letters saying 'error', lol.

Comment: I suppose I'll leave the question up, since someone may find it useful :)

Comment: You can say `byte b = (byte)123134235;`.  Try it and see what happens.

Comment: Ahh, that's interesting, printed as '121'.

Comment: byte b = (byte)123134235 that is casting..read this http://voidexception.weebly.com/type-casting-in-java-i---type-casting-primitive-data-types.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you cast your assignment to a byte it will overflow,

```
byte b = (byte) 123134235;
byte u = (byte) (Byte.MIN_VALUE - 1);
byte o = (byte) (Byte.MAX_VALUE + 1);

System.out.printf("b = %d, u = %d, o = %d%n", (int) b, (int) u, (int) o);
```

`u` is an example of underflow (1 less then the minimum valid byte), while `o` is another example of overflow (1 more then the maximum valid byte). And the output is,

```
b = 27, u = 127, o = -128
```

Which tells us that `byte` has the range -128 to 127, and that `(123134235 % 256)` is 27.

Comment: Ohh, so when I did `byte b = (byte) 123134235;` it gave me 121 because that's what (123134235 % 256) is :)

Comment: @user3839220 I get 27. Check it again, because 121 isn't right.

Comment: No, the number you entered is different to my number :) 123134235 != 123134235

Comment: It is, and 123134235-(480993*256) = 27.

Comment: Wait no, the number I put in is: 123252345, you put in 123134235

Comment: @user3839220  Sorry. I used the number in your question. yeah, not using the same numbers explains that!

Comment: @user3839220 You're right about the result being `123134235 % 256`, but keep in mind that if you say `(byte)x` and `x % 256` is in the 128-255 range, the result will actually be `(x % 256) - 256`.

Comment: @user3839220 The byte value must be between -128 and 127. When you perform `123134235 % 256` you have an int value.

Answer (score 1):

What you have here

```
byte b = 123134235;
```

is a constant expression where a narrowing primitive conversion would be attempted. [The Java Language Specification states](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.2)

> A narrowing primitive conversion may be used if the type of the
>   variable is byte, short, or char, and the value of the constant
>   expression is representable in the type of the variable.

The value, the integer literal `123134235` is not representable by the type `byte` and so compilation fails.

Answer (score 0):

`byte b = 123134235;` will not even compile: so the compiler is doing nothing except refusing to compile it.

In Eclipse with Java 7, I get the following compilation error for this declaration and initialization:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
    Type mismatch: cannot convert from int to byte
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all `byte b = 123134235;` wont compile upon `compile time` that is because it is a type `int` you cant store `int` into a `byte` without casting it.

```
But what is the Java compiler actually doing? Is it just storing the value as 123... or?
```

It is actually storing it but instead it will overflow from positive to negative that is because byte is only 8-bit signed two's complement integer.

Now lets calculate it using `modulos`:

```
System.out.println(b % Byte.MIN_VALUE);
```

the remainder will be the real value of byte which is **27**